# What is the public key file that is generated by PuTTY?

Tags: ssh, putty, openssh

If I'm using the PuTTY key generator to create a public/private key pair, there is a button to "Save public key" like so:

[image: Highlighted button in the PuTTY Key Generator window]

However OpenSSH doesn't accept the format of this public key file, at least as far as I can tell. The generated public key looks like this:

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20140607"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAs+UjC01Fk8xs8vpLW1RIipwxG1zXTaCkIdeJ
K3SyhMVl78/QwErTYuIop3wVmVAuTKhw4uYCMaRZCy36FdSGQ9FwDCP+lT36M2Xv
ZtraweH+1IPHzRf2ENNdEfs286zllu96WGtqLYwObXQbHMm3dPDDbH3apynrS/FJ
HisCayFXFN84aBfh9HFHrM++BXqpxTX5nq50QoRwSjMY6qMuLwjJKKQslcb5hlRV
SjCmUZKv9/fH+i0BI7UHJ01XHNp1sisL5biWkakXD9BxXjv/ggyeLsOTtdtrF0DK
7wYQXyNmpRqHYOBdrZlskHf/R1CtWoBi5IIeARWZVDduXf1Pww==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

**(Key is not an actual public key)**

Where is this key used typically? Does it work with OpenSSH at all?

Comment: There's 3 kinds of key pairs PuTTY Keygen can generate, what kind are you using?

Comment: I'm using it as shown in the screenshot. If I generate the private key I can copy/paste the public key out of the box at the top and paste it into the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys without issue, but I can't use the file generated when I click on the "Save Public Key" button since it appears to be a different format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSH uses a different format for public keys.  This is the format used in the window showing the key for pasting.  You can past this into a new notepad document if you want it in a file.  Normally, the public key is pasted into an authorized_key file on the server you want to connect to.

Putty uses a multi-line format that includes a header and footer.  This is the format it saves the file in.

The OpenSSH authorized_keys file allows additional information to be added to the line containing the public key.  This data can be used to control what the key can be used for.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

For the example key you provided (output by PuTTY):

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20140607"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAs+UjC01Fk8xs8vpLW1RIipwxG1zXTaCkIdeJ
K3SyhMVl78/QwErTYuIop3wVmVAuTKhw4uYCMaRZCy36FdSGQ9FwDCP+lT36M2Xv
ZtraweH+1IPHzRf2ENNdEfs286zllu96WGtqLYwObXQbHMm3dPDDbH3apynrS/FJ
HisCayFXFN84aBfh9HFHrM++BXqpxTX5nq50QoRwSjMY6qMuLwjJKKQslcb5hlRV
SjCmUZKv9/fH+i0BI7UHJ01XHNp1sisL5biWkakXD9BxXjv/ggyeLsOTtdtrF0DK
7wYQXyNmpRqHYOBdrZlskHf/R1CtWoBi5IIeARWZVDduXf1Pww==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

The one-line format (eg as expected by `authorized_keys`) is:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAs+UjC01Fk8xs8vpLW1RIipwxG1zXTaCkIdeJK3SyhMVl78/QwErTYuIop3wVmVAuTKhw4uYCMaRZCy36FdSGQ9FwDCP+lT36M2XvZtraweH+1IPHzRf2ENNdEfs286zllu96WGtqLYwObXQbHMm3dPDDbH3apynrS/FJHisCayFXFN84aBfh9HFHrM++BXqpxTX5nq50QoRwSjMY6qMuLwjJKKQslcb5hlRVSjCmUZKv9/fH+i0BI7UHJ01XHNp1sisL5biWkakXD9BxXjv/ggyeLsOTtdtrF0DK7wYQXyNmpRqHYOBdrZlskHf/R1CtWoBi5IIeARWZVDduXf1Pww==
```

There's no magical command to convert here. If you look close, I just removed a few lines, removed the newlines, and prepended it with `ssh-rsa`

## Explanation

The default format that putty uses is defined in [RFC4716](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4716).

From `man ssh-keygen`, `ssh-keygen` supports 3x formats:

1. RFC4716
2. PKCS8
3. PEM

> ```
>  -m key_format
>         Specify a key format for the -i (import) or -e (export) conver‐
>         sion options.  The supported key formats are: “RFC4716” (RFC
>         4716/SSH2 public or private key), “PKCS8” (PEM PKCS8 public key)
>         or “PEM” (PEM public key).  The default conversion format is
>         “RFC4716”.  Setting a format of “PEM” when generating or updating
>         a supported private key type will cause the key to be stored in
>         the legacy PEM private key format.
> ```

The default used by `ssh-keygen` and PuTTY is actually the same (RFC4716), except that the `id_rsa.pub` file puts it on one line, which is what the `authorized_keys` file expects.

### Example Key

For example, I'll generate a new key in Debian 10:

```
user@disp8452:~$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:lrwmOoBF1PEtDbbVkFwREgWqdJlH5ViEYzQpUAyPyNY user@disp8452
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
| ...+*+oX&Oo     |
| ..o.=o@B*.      |
| .+ E Xo=..      |
| ... o + .       |
| o  .   S        |
|. .    . .       |
|   .  . o        |
|    .. o         |
|    ..           |
+----[SHA256]-----+
user@disp8452:~$ cat /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzU4exWqu4tsgWIJleq1AJ98cGHswD80cphWYOasspBoOPgdv1rljgb9PFAQX19X+rofYi+aYd1glP8BhRC3rt4zE26J54h8tt46DBT1TkFPJ2O3ULhLSqcv9zENGkGB0bfXkvhI0p/tP4b1a0NnvmNME9i6qyo8/7mPLovaKwP1qkd7/a+p1DQr2XoId9U6G4rx0TKsvhbjmDvaCWAm4c5LT3WbQHh301DWiwsN8xn8LkxaO4GtdIqxHOyj7lmQZGw8ixuvoIY/FjgXhSPGmaWLyz2o45TrTNP7vWxWqgcDi2CegziD67+UN4tBZvB9HwR6V3aaCrV59H15ukAtK1 user@disp8452
user@disp8452:~$
```

#### RFC4716

You can get that in the PuTTY RFC4716 format as follows:

```
user@disp8452:~$ ssh-keygen -ef /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -mRFC4716
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "2048-bit RSA, converted by user@disp8452 from OpenSSH"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCzU4exWqu4tsgWIJleq1AJ98cGHswD80cphWYOas
spBoOPgdv1rljgb9PFAQX19X+rofYi+aYd1glP8BhRC3rt4zE26J54h8tt46DBT1TkFPJ2
O3ULhLSqcv9zENGkGB0bfXkvhI0p/tP4b1a0NnvmNME9i6qyo8/7mPLovaKwP1qkd7/a+p
1DQr2XoId9U6G4rx0TKsvhbjmDvaCWAm4c5LT3WbQHh301DWiwsN8xn8LkxaO4GtdIqxHO
yj7lmQZGw8ixuvoIY/FjgXhSPGmaWLyz2o45TrTNP7vWxWqgcDi2CegziD67+UN4tBZvB9
HwR6V3aaCrV59H15ukAtK1
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
user@disp8452:~$
```

Note that the fingerprint line is actually the same, so you can manually convert between the multi-line format output by PuTTY and the one-line format just by removing the `BEGIN`, `Comment`, and `END` lines. Then remove newlines and prepend it with `ssh-rsa` .

#### PKCS8

And to be complete, here's the PKCS8 format of the key above:

```
user@disp8452:~$ ssh-keygen -ef /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -mPKCS8
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAs1OHsVqruLbIFiCZXqtQ
CffHBh7MA/NHKYVmDmrLKQaDj4Hb9a5Y4G/TxQEF9fV/q6H2IvmmHdYJT/AYUQt6
7eMxNuieeIfLbeOgwU9U5BTydjt1C4S0qnL/cxDRpBgdG315L4SNKf7T+G9WtDZ7
5jTBPYuqsqPP+5jy6L2isD9apHe/2vqdQ0K9l6CHfVOhuK8dEyrL4W45g72glgJu
HOS091m0B4d9NQ1osLDfMZ/C5MWjuBrXSKsRzso+5ZkGRsPIsbr6CGPxY4F4Ujxp
mli8s9qOOU60zT+71sVqoHA4tgnoM4g+u/lDeLQWbwfR8Eeld2mgq1efR9ebpALS
tQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
user@disp8452:~$
```

#### PEM

And the PEM format:

```
user@disp8452:~$ ssh-keygen -ef /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -mPEM
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAs1OHsVqruLbIFiCZXqtQCffHBh7MA/NHKYVmDmrLKQaDj4Hb9a5Y
4G/TxQEF9fV/q6H2IvmmHdYJT/AYUQt67eMxNuieeIfLbeOgwU9U5BTydjt1C4S0
qnL/cxDRpBgdG315L4SNKf7T+G9WtDZ75jTBPYuqsqPP+5jy6L2isD9apHe/2vqd
Q0K9l6CHfVOhuK8dEyrL4W45g72glgJuHOS091m0B4d9NQ1osLDfMZ/C5MWjuBrX
SKsRzso+5ZkGRsPIsbr6CGPxY4F4Ujxpmli8s9qOOU60zT+71sVqoHA4tgnoM4g+
u/lDeLQWbwfR8Eeld2mgq1efR9ebpALStQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
user@disp8452:~$
```